# How to (selectively) detect closed shapes from contours

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having a trouble finding out a way to mask the painted area(from the image below).
From contours, shape detection only seems to be detecting the rope instead, not the area it's forming.

Can anyone help me out what codes I should add in order to achieve this?
I'm using python and OpenCV

Here's my code.

```
lower_red = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
upper_red = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel)
else:
   
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
   
        cv2.drawContours(cropFrame, cnt, -1, (0, 0, 0), 1)
```

Thank you.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: What are your actual values for your lower and upper colors? Did you view your mask to be sure your ranges were good and you got what you expected?

Comment: @fmw42 Yes The values are adjustable, meaning I'm able to select the ropes here. But since the painted area has the same value with other backgrounds.. that's where the issue begins

Comment: Is the painted area painted or is that just for explanation?

Comment: @fmw42 just for explanation.